# How to pass List<E> from RecyclerView Adapter to RecyclerView Holder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to find the answer to my question above but no post seems to help. I have a RecyclerView Adapter where I get the data as List from a database:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    public List<Note> noteList;
    private View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Note> noteList, View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener, Context context) {
        this.noteList = noteList;
        this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

And a ViewHolder where I have an onClickListener to find the position of the view clicked using `getLayoutPosition()`:

```
static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView noteTitleText;
        private TextView noteDescriptionText;
        private TextView dateText;
        private TextView weekText;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            noteTitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noteTitleText);
            noteDescriptionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noteDescriptionText);
            dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            weekText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weekText);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getLayoutPosition();

            // I want the noteList from the RecyclerViewAdapter here.
            Note note = noteList.get(position); 

            Log.d("Item Clicked", String.valueOf(position));

        }
    }
```

The purpose is that I need the noteList with all the notes from the RecyclerViewAdapter in the onClick() method to populate an Activity using an intent. How should I go about this?

Comment: If you are using the position to index into the data structure that backs your adapter (which it looks like you are), you should use `getAdapterPosition()` instead of `getLayoutPosition()`. The layout position and adapter position will usually be synced, but the layout position can report a different value if items in your adapter have been moved/changed and the recyclerview hasn't had a chance to draw the updates yet.

Comment: @BenP. Thanks for noticing that out.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out solutions for an hour, here's what I settled on. Instead of implementing OnClickListener in ViewHolder, I implemented it in RecyclerViewAdapter in onBindViewHolder() method, as:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Note note = noteList.get(position);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // The note and noteList can be accessed here.
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The compiler is happy to let you do it, but from an Android perspective, it is an error to declare `position` as final. The implementation of RecyclerView is such that viewholders can be "moved" without being re-bound, so this `position` parameter is only valid at the instant the viewholder is being bound. Despite that `position` parameter being available, you should still retrieve the position of the viewholder using `getAdapterPosition()` from within the click listener. Edit: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imsr8NrIAMs @ 35:00 for official statement.

Comment: @BenP. Thanks for sharing this! That was the only way I found it working so I proceed with the above code. Do you mean I should replace `noteList.get(position)` with `noteList.get(getAdapterPosition())`?